# How do I create a page flip effect programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm pretty sure I can create a page flip effect using a series of PNGs to simulate the animation but is there a way to do it programmatically? Tried googling it and looking at Apple sample code but didn't see anything addressing that particular animation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean for an iPhone, right?

From the [Apple API](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:) docs for UIView:

```
+ (void)setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransition)transition forView:(UIView *)view cache:(BOOL)cache
```

where `UIViewAnimationTransition` is defined as:

```
typedef enum {
   UIViewAnimationTransitionNone,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
   UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown,
} UIViewAnimationTransition;
```

`UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp` is what you are looking for. See those docs for information on how to start, set, and commit animations to views as well.

Comment: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp and UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown are iOS 4.0 only.  Also, they don't offer a left / right curl.